# How to create an empty table with specific schema in GBQ?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a schema in a .json file and I want to create an empty table with it, in Google Big Query.

I am using 
`pandas_gbq.to_gbq(dataframe=None, destination_table="{}.{}".format(dataset, table), project_id=project_id, if_exists="fail", table_schema=schema, credentials=credentials_obj)`

But I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`

How can I create an empty table with my own schema with pandas_gbq?

**Edit to add schema requested in comments.**

```
    [
  {
    "name": "my_first_col",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "my_2nd_col",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a sample of the schema you are trying to use?

Comment: Hey @S.Tyr I added a sample of how my schema looks like, the schema has way more fields. But I really think the issue lies to the fact that the Dataframe being empty and therefore having no columns to act as fields in the table. I wanted the schema to assume that part and fill the fields.

Comment: I'm wondering if the root cause is really "empty". How about creating a table with one row to make sure the code really works with "non-empty" table?

Comment: @YunZhang I made a `pandas.DataFrame({"my_first_co;": [1,2,3], "my_2nd_col": [3, 4, 5]})` to replace the `None` dataframe in the function and it worked. And then I tried again with `pandas.DataFrame.empty` and I got the same error. So I am still trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated the "AttributeError" message is because you are not passing a valid object to the pandas_gbq.to_gbq() method. So I recommend you to pass a new pandas.DataFrame object, without parameters.

I made the next to replicate what you are asking for, and it worked:

```
import pandas
import pandas_gbq

schema = [
        {"name": "my_first_col", "type": "INTEGER"},
        {"name": "my_2nd_col", "type": "INTEGER"}
    ]

df = pandas.DataFrame()
dataset = "my_dataset"
table = "my_table"
project_id = "my_project_id"

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(dataframe=df, destination_table="{}.{}".format(dataset, table), project_id=project_id, if_exists="fail", table_schema=schema)
```

The method is expecting to receive a pandas.DataFrame object to work with, that's why using a None object from python is breaking your call to the pandas_gbq.to_gbq() method. I hope this solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

S. Tyr's answer mostly worked for me, but I found that the schema was not associated with the new table in BigQuery. To address this, I made a list comprising the column names and passed it into pandas.DataFrame as an argument like this:

```
schema = [
        {"name": "my_first_col", "type": "INTEGER"},
        {"name": "my_2nd_col", "type": "INTEGER"}
    ]
column_names = list()
for record in schema:
    column_names.append(record['name'])
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
```

The remainder of S. Tyr's code worked for me. (For completeness I am re-stating it below, but credit goes to S. Tyr)

```
dataset = "my_dataset"
table = "my_table"
project_id = "my_project_id"

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(dataframe=df, destination_table="{}.{}".format(dataset, table), project_id=project_id, if_exists="fail", table_schema=schema)
```